# Acceder al contenido de $fillable sin pasar por $fillable. Intentando entender la asignacion masiva

Tags: php, laravel, poo

Siguiendo un tutorial he visto que su creador usaba algo que no habia visto hasta ahora que era acceder directamente al contenido de los atributos de una clase sin pasar directamente por el attributo. Me ha comentado que esto se llama asignacion masiva, he buscado informacion en la documentacion de laravel pero debe ser muy basico por que no lo especifica bien.

Un ejemplo

Modelo Users

```
protected $fillable = ['nombre','apellidos','direccion,'codigo postal','email','contraseña'];


public function emailUsuario()
{
    return $this->email ;
}
```

Ahi viene mi duda(no entiendo esa funcion), probablemente sea lo mas facil del mundo y cuando realizas una consulta al modelo desde otro modelo tal que asi.

```
$usuario = New User();
$usuario->email = $request->email

$usuario->save
```

o

```
User::create([$request->email])
```

Lo entiendo mucho mejor, no obstante como digo, lo entiendo cuando es desde otro modelo pero si intentas acceder al contenido de un atributo desde la misma clase me cuesta mas entenderlo

Esto es lo que no entiendo

```
"return $this->email"
```

Aqui realmente accedemos al campo email como si fuera un atributo de clase, es decir como si email estuviese asi

```
protected $email;
```

pero ¿no deberia ser?

```
"return $this->fillable["email"]"
```

Aqui si pasamos por la variable fillable

Espero que se entienda lo  que quiero argumentar

¿Alguien me puede explicar por que no pasamos por fillable y aun asi es completamente correcto?

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el propósito del `$fillable`. Este se utiliza para agregar una capa de seguridad, el `$fillable` establece que atributos se pueden asignar cuando se ejecutan las funciones masivas `create` o `new` en un modelo (Espefica qué campos sí quieres que se guarden en la base de datos). Por otro lado, para acceder a los valores del modelo se utiliza por ejemplo: `$this->email` como mencionas y esto es independiente de lo que tengas en `$fillable`.

Comment: La propiedad **$protected** existe en el modelo para proteger y organizar que campos se pueden asignar o no de forma masiva, ya que por defecto todos están "bloqueados". Y no, no funciona como un arreglo en donde se guarden los atributos de tu modelo.

Answer (score 0):

La vqriable **$fillable** es la lista de atributos(variables dentro de la clase) que puedes **asignar de forma masiva**.
Asignar de forma masiva simplemente signifca que guardas los datos usando un vector (corrijanme si es otro nomre pero aun asi se entiende).
**Ejemplo:** si tu modelo tiene atributo1 y atributo2, y $fillables es:

```
$fillable = ['atributo1'];
```

Forma clasica de guardar un nuevo modelo:

```
$modelo = new Modelo;
$modelo->atributo1 = $var1;
$modelo->atributo2 = $var2;
$modelo->save();
```

Asignamiento masivo:

```
$modelo = Modelo::create(['atributo1' => $var1]);
```

La principal diferencia de cada uno de los dos es que el modo clasico uriliza una linea de codigo por cada ateibuto que uses y solo funciona un objeto a la vez pero con la ventaja que puedes asignar valores a los atributos aun si no estan en la lista de $fillable. En cambio el modo masivo puedes acerlo en una linea de codigo pero no te dejara asignar valores a los ateibutos que no esten en la lista $fillable.
 Con respecto a la funcion que retorna el email, esta bien escrita solo que estas confundiendo el uso de la variable $fillable.
Esa funcion simplemente aparece porque al mostrarte el cosigo de una sola linea de $fillable apareciodentro de la captura o algo asi y no tiene que ver una con la otra.